# CSS Rollover Working But Link Is Not

Tags: css-sprites

I have been working on building my first CSS site using divs and am having an issue with a button. While I am able to get the button to work on rollover, the link does not respond. Can somebody please advise. Thank you.

HTML:

```
 <div class="wrapArrow">   

 <div class="arrow" style="cursor: pointer;"><a href="../index.html" title="home"    target="_self"><span>home</span></a></div>

 </div><!-- END wrapArrow -->
```

CSS:

```
.wrapArrow {
margin: 70px 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
float: right;
}


.arrow {
display: block;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background-image: url(../images/nav/arrows.gif);
background-repeat:  no-repeat;

}


.arrow:hover { 
  background-position: 0 -20px; }


.arrow span {
 display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `<span>` is not displayed, your link has no content, so it gets collapsed to a width and height of 0, thus making it unclickable.

Why not just make the anchor itself have the `arrow` class?

```
<div class="wrapArrow">   

<a href="../index.html" title="home" target="_self" class="arrow" style="cursor: pointer;"><span>home</span></a>

</div><!-- END wrapArrow -->​
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a little strange, but it worked the first time I clicked. Then when I clicked back to try again it doesn't work. Why would that happen?

Comment: I am still trying to solve this issue and would greatly appreciate some assistance in resolving the problem. As mentioned, I tried the advice from above without full success. While the click does now work on the first page load, it does not work if I return to the page. The rollover effect works perfectly, it's the click that is causing the issue. Why is this happening and how do I fix it? Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @user862307: When you say click: you're clicking the link and then what; using the back arrow to return to the previous page? I can't think of anything that would cause a link to become unclickable on returning to the page.

Comment: Actually. Just got it to work after dumping the cache. The code above seems to work perfectly. Thanks so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to get rid of

```
.arrow span {
    display: none;
}
```

Is there any reason that needs to be there? With display set to none you are hiding the clickable element that is necessary for the link to work.

Comment: This didn't work. Without the span the text appears over the background image. The text works as a link, but I don't want to see it.

Answer (score 1):

`.arrow a` is `0 x 0 px`

Makes it really hard to click. Believe me I tried.

Try:

```
        .arrow a {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: block;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. This also worked like the answer above. Worked the first time I clicked. Then when I clicked back to try again it doesn't work. Very strange.